# On the expression "some... and not others"

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I want to ask a simple question.

One often uses *some* and *and not others* or *but not others* together. For instance:

> (1) Why does cancer attack **some tissues but not others**?
>   (2) Why do interventions work in **some places and not others**?

Is *and not others* or *but not others* put after *some* just to emphasize the noun after *some*?

Comment: Question isn't clear (is not a real question) because the two examples do not include the characters "(but)", while the question does.  Are you asking when to put *but* in parentheses after *and*?

Comment: Sorry. No. I'm asking why you use "and not others" or "but not others" after "some". If "and not others" or "but not others" is taken away, its meaning does not change.

Comment: No, it is not to emphasize the noun after *some*. Quite the opposite, in fact: it takes emphasis *away* from the noun and puts it on the word *some* instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for emphasis and also to avoid ambiguity: "Some" does not necessarily mean "some but not all". It can mean "at least one, maybe all". So adding "and not others" ensures that you don't mean it that way.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I never knew that if there is only "some", it could mean "at least one, maybe all".

Comment: Like if you asked, "Can SOMEONE give me a ride home?", you are looking for at least one. If everyone present was able to give you a ride, you wouldn't say that the answer is "no" because it's all and not "just some". But if you said, "Some, but not all, of our employees have college degrees", then if it turned out that in fact 100% had college degrees, this statement would be false.

Answer (score 3):

*Some* usually represents an [Existential Quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification). That's one of two types of [logical](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) quantifiers (the other is the Universal Quantifier, usually represented in English by *each, every,* and *all*).

The existential quantifier asserts the existence of (for count nouns) at least one object,  **or** (for mass nouns) at least some minimum quantity -- and maybe more in both cases -- of whatever argument it binds. The universal quantifier refers to **all** of whatever it binds.

They are related in the sense that if something is true for *All X*, then it's clearly true for *Some X*; while if all we know is that it's true of *Some X*, we can conclude nothing about its truth for *All X*. If **all** Hoosiers were left-handed, then certainly **some** Hoosiers would be. But all we know is that **some** Hoosiers are left-handed, so we just don't know about **all** Hoosiers.

This is logic -- not, strictly speaking, grammar -- but English, like all languages, does have quantifiers as a normal part of speech, and the meanings of these particular quantifiers are modelled fairly well by [Quantified Predicate Calculus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: Absolutely true, and very obtusely worded!

Answer (score 0):

This expression is often used where there is clear evidence of both sides of the issue - so there is evidence available that some tissues get cancer, and that others don't.

Just saying "why some tissues get cancer" suggests that some occasions have been identified where this is the case, but none where it is definitively not.

The emphasis is not identifying why some get cancer, but what is the difference between those that do and those that don't. Addressing "Why some tissues get cancer" can be about identifying the reasons for a range of tissues to get cancer, whereas "why some do and not others" is a different approach, to identify what the difference is between the groups that do and the ones that don't.